# static files request reach controllers

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have this in my `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                    IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

And the following action in my controller

```
[Route("{*catchAll}")]
Public IActionResult Index(string catchAll)
{
  ...
}
```

Debugging my app, I get request such as `/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js`, etc. hitting my action. I thought `app.UseStaticFiles()` will short-circuit such request. What could be the problem here?

**edit:**

my bad. I forgot to "`bower`" restore my client-side packages, thus the said files weren't added to the pipeline.

Comment: The request examples you gave are to folders, not files. Are requests to actual files giving the same result?

Comment: they are actually files requests. edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Order in `startup.cs` is important. Put `app.UseStaticFiles();` before `app.UseMvc` in `Configure` section

Comment: I checked on my test solution and it worked in this configuration